# Bridge from just basic bricks?

Tags: building, bridge

I teach an after-school engineering class using LEGO bricks, one of our classes has the students build a bridge.  Each student gets a custom set of about 150 2x4 bricks, about 300 2x2 bricks, and, if I'm feeling generous, about 15 2x8 plates.  Although I've seen many fancy bridges made with technic parts, I've never seen an awesome bridge made with just basic bricks.  I'm looking for a reference bridge to show the kids, after the build their own, what is possible.  So, show me the best bridge (either a link to someone else's bridge , or a photo of your own) that can be made with just basic bricks!

Scope note: Most people don't have this custom set of bricks, so links or pictures of any bridge that uses almost no rare parts and use almost no technics would be cool.

Background:

LEGO Bridge Page: http://lego.sparre-andersen.dk//Transport/Broer/

Arch from [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20071014143559/http://www.weirdrichard.com/images/arches1.jpg)
[image: arch]

Cantilever from [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20071014143404/http://www.weirdrichard.com/images/canta.jpg)
[image: cantilever]

Big:  from [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20070220113147/http://weirdrichard.com:80/images/ruffes.jpg)
[image: big lego thing]

Sort of basic arch: from [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/doctorsinister/5047678593/)
[image: large arched bridge]

Comment: From the FAQ:

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about __”, then you should not be asking here.

Comment: I don't think "off-topic" is the right close vote here...

Comment: I think a better question would have been: How do we make [this bridge - with picture] more robust? With a picture of the bridge in question, or something like "How would you go about about building a functional Cantilever bridge using the following components?" and then tag it [tag:technique] or similar

Comment: I disagree that this is off topic.  I think Joubarc's answer is perfect.  The question is practical - I face this problem.  And although it is open ended, it is not inherently open ended, any more than any 'what is the best'  type of question, which are often asked and answer, for example, on stack overflow.  I do like Zhaph - Ben Duguid's suggestion as being significantly more constructive and less discouraging than simply closing this.

Comment: Pubby8 asked this http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-is-a-good-ratio-to-buy-bricks-in I feel that either these should both be closed, or neither should be.

Comment: I think Lee DeLapp was just plain wrong. This question should not have been closed.

Comment: @ErikOlson and AscendlyJJ: At this stage (private beta), both of you should be able to vote to reopen this (I have done), or vote to close the others. Oezi's question as originally asked was even more off topic, being related specifically to programming mindstorms. Just commenting doesn't really help ;)

Comment: I've added this as a meta topic for discussion http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/59/will-all-open-ended-questions-be-closed-i-certainly-hope-not

Comment: Ok, I never saw a reopen on stackexcange before!

Comment: @ascendlyJJ: "What's the best" questions are such a pox on SO the word "best" automatically pops up a warning when asking a question! Please don't try to justify this question with that example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you also want them to be aware of the solidity of their bridge, you may want to have a look at this [contest](http://www.philohome.com/bridge/bridge.htm).

Note that bridges made of stacked plates are much more solid than Technic ones.

Comment: To prevent the stack-of-plate loophole, most Lego bridge contest now have a weight limit.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention an engineering class, I assume you probably mean a functional bridge that can be tested for capacity.

This bridge may not withstand a great deal of weight, but it appears in a 1964 LEGO Idea Book and is created only from basic bricks available at that time. (LEGO did issue a more detailed Tower Bridge set a few years ago)

[image: LEGO Tower Bridge]